# Display empty address bar when overriding about:newtab in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions, manifest.json

I have just ported an extension that alters the about:newtab page from Chrome to Firefox.

This is done like this (from *manifest.json*):

```
...
"chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "index.html"
},
...
```

Google Chrome does not display anything in the address bar, but the Firefox version of my extension displays *moz-extension://some-hex-string/index.html*.

Is there a way to make Firefox display an empty address bar in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I've found out that it's an issue that's being looked into, at the moment there is no solution. See here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1372996

**EDIT:** It's coming in version 57.

Comment: I mean, technically it's already RESOLVED/FIXED with FF 57 as target release.